# My drop down menu only opens if I am fast enough

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, slideshow

I'm working on a website and I need to include a drop-down menu and a slide show. They both work okay, but when I try to open the drop-down menu, I have to be really fast in order to keep the menu open. I think the reason for that has something to do with the code for the slideshow in css.

CSS

```
/*Slideshow*/

#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0.49;
  margin: -0.7%;
}

#slideshow > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

/* I think the problem is whats right above this text.*/

/*Dropdown Menu*/

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropbtn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.headerB c:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: white;
  color: #2099ba;
}

.dropbtn {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 19px;
  font-family: "Catamaran", sans-serif;
  float: right;
  left: 1300px;
  position: absolute;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  right: 90px;
  top: 175px;
}

.dropdown-content c {
  float: float;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content c:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css">
  <script src = "homepage.js"> </script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Catamaran:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<title> COVID PAGE</title>

<div class="headerB">
  <header>
      <div class="containerB">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn">☰
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <c href="#">Home</c>
                <c href="#">Transportation</c>
                <c href="#">Mask Guidelines</c>
                <c href="#">Lunch</c>
                <c href="#">Maps</c>
                <c href="#">Dr. D's Emails</c>
                <c href="#">COVID-19 Education</c>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ul>

        </nav>
      </div>
  </header>
</div>

<!--Slideshow-->
<div id="slideshow">
  <div>
       <img src="slideshow/lowerSchool.jpg" style= width:100%>
     </div>
     <div>
       <img src="slideshow/newMs.jpg" style=width:100% >
     </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="slideshow/stem1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="slideshow/stem2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="slideshow/kleinWalkway.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="slideshow/leggettField.jpg" style="width:100%">

  </div>


  </div>
</html
```

Can anyone help me find what is wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: insert your html

Comment: @sergey kuznetsov ok i just did

Answer (score 1):

do you need it? if not, then speak as needed, I will redo it.

```css
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0.49;
  margin: -0.7%;
}

#slideshow > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
`I think the problem is whats right above this text.`


/*Dropdown Menu*/



/*.dropbtn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}*/

.headerB c:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: white;
  color: #2099ba;
}

.dropdown {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    float: right;
    overflow: unset;
}

.dropbtn {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 19px;
  font-family: "Catamaran", sans-serif;
  float: right;
  /*left: 1300px;*/
  /*position: absolute;*/
   background-color: inherit;
   margin: 0;
   border: none;
  margin: 0;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  right: 90px;
  top: 175px;
}

.dropdown-content c {
  float: float;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content c:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css">
  <script src = "homepage.js"> </script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Catamaran:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<title> COVID PAGE</title>

<div class="headerB">
  <header>
      <div class="containerB">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn">☰
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <c href="#">Home</c>
                <c href="#">Transportation</c>
                <c href="#">Mask Guidelines</c>
                <c href="#">Lunch</c>
                <c href="#">Maps</c>
                <c href="#">Dr. D's Emails</c>
                <c href="#">COVID-19 Education</c>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ul>

        </nav>
      </div>
  </header>
</div>

<!--Slideshow-->
<div id="slideshow">
  <div>
       <img src="slideshow/lowerSchool.jpg" style= width:100%>
     </div>
     <div>
       <img src="slideshow/newMs.jpg" style=width:100% >
     </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="slideshow/stem1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="slideshow/stem2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="slideshow/kleinWalkway.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="slideshow/leggettField.jpg" style="width:100%">

  </div>


  </div>
</html
```

Comment: Please note that asking people to accept your answer is discouraged, especially so soon after it is asked. It is up to the person asking if they want to wait for more answers, and whether or not to accept any answer.

Comment: @sergeykuz this menu is necessary for the website to function. Do you know any ways to fix this?

Comment: @LillyBella it doesn’t sound like your problem is fixed? If it is not resolved, then you shouldn’t accept an answer (you can still upvote it if it was helpful) because that marks the question as resolved. This means that no one else will look at your question to give any more help because they will think your problem is solved. If you still need help, you can unaccept the answer for now and you can also edit your question if you have any more information.

Comment: If I haven't solved the issue completely, I'm ready to solve the problem the way the author wants. What else needs to be done?

Comment: @Lilly Bella, what result do you want to see?

Comment: @LillyBella so now you need to tell us what problem is still happening any why this answer didn't work! And Sergey: Your answer should include an explanation of how it fixes the problem in the question. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow for this very reason :) If your code doesn't work exactly, the OP might still be able to use the code and get it to work if you explain what exactly it is doing.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I want the menu to drop down when the icon is hovered over but it has to stay out so that the user can get to the menu.

Comment: @Lilly Bella, the width of the dropdown menu should be full screen? is the width the same as now in my solution?

Comment: do you need it?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov no the width should stay the same as it is now. the menu and slideshow are both necessary for the website.

Comment: @Lilly Bella, I redid my solution. Check it out.